# Send SMS in USA with a PHP API

Tags: php, service, sms

Where I can find an enterprice API(PHP) to send SMS in USA?

I am looking for an API that will be easy to use, also allows me view reports of sended SMS, that also has documentation and examples to how manage it.

Comment: take a look at https://www.tropo.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.twilio.com/ is a good service and they have a PHP library http://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/

Comment: Happy to answer any Twilio questions for you

Answer (score 3):

- Twilio: http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/sms/hello-monkey
- Tropo: http://blog.tropo.com/2009/08/25/add-sms-and-im-to-any-existing-tropo-application-in-ruby-python-php-javascript-or-groovy-today/

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look to the open source projects on PHP script at

http://www.aldeaglobal.net/callserver/

and another one is this:

http://www.simong.net/finarea/

They work on more than 20 providers, and the APIs are quite similar.

A comparision matrix for all prices can be found here:

`hXXp//progx.ch/home-voip-smsbetamax-3-1-1.html`
(replace hXXp by http: sorry I'm new and I need more reputation to post more than 2 links maybe you can vote me ;-)

All of these Providers are compatible with the two PHP scripts above.

Most of those providers also have an official API which is in most of the cases here:

`https://provider_name.com/myaccount/sendsms.php?username=XXXX&password=XXXX&from=00XXXX&to=00XXXX&text=XXXX`

Just replace the *XXXX* and open it with a **fsockopen** using the ssl:// or https://